# Validation of an inline formset conditional to the value of a field from the parent form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I want to use custom validation in a django inline formset (`form_date_event`) so that I get different validation according to one value on the parent (`form_event`) form.

Specifically, I'd like the `form_date_event` inline formset to accept an empty venue if the type of the `form_event` is 'recording release'. How can I achieve that? The `type = cleaned_data.get('type')` below doesn't work, I suppose because it's getting the `clean data` of the formset, not of the parent form.

`models.py`:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Event(models.Model):

    EV_TYPE = (
        ('performance', 'performance'),
        ('recording release', 'recording release'),
        ('other', 'other'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EV_TYPE, default="performance")


class dateEvent(models.Model):

    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            'type',
            'title',
        ]
```

`views.py`:

```
class BaseDateEventFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        type = cleaned_data.get('type')

        if type == 'recording release':
            self.add_error('repertoire', _("This field is required"))

        return cleaned_data


def event_edit_view(request, id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=id)
    active_user = request.user
    form_event = EventForm(request.POST or None, instance=event)
    DateEventFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Event, dateEvent, extra=5, can_delete=True, fields=('event', 'start_date_time', 'venue', 'link', 'link_description'),
    form_date_event = DateEventFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=Event.objects.get(id=id), prefix="dateEvent", queryset=dateEvent.objects.filter(event__id=id))


    context = {
        'event': event,
        'id': event.id,
        'form_event': form_event,
        'form_date_event': form_date_event,

        }

    if request.method == "POST":

        if form_event.is_valid() and request.POST['action'] == 'submit':
            if form_date_event.is_valid():

                flag=False
                evt_type = form_event.cleaned_data.get('type')
                for form in form_date_event:
                    print(form.cleaned_data.get('venue'))
                    if form.cleaned_data.get('venue') is None and evt_type !="recording release":
                        flag = True
                        break
                if flag:
                    messages.error(request,'Venue can be blank only for recording release events')
                    return render(request, "events/event-edit.html", context)
                else:
                    form_event.save()
                    form_date_event.save()
                    return redirect('my-events')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(form_date_event.errors)

        elif form_event.is_valid() and form_date_event.is_valid() and request.POST['action'] == 'update':
            form_event.save()
            form_date_event.save()


        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError([form_event.errors, form_date_event.errors])

    return render(request, "events/event-edit.html", context)
```

Comment: what do you mean by accept an empty venue? you mean `None`?

Comment: I mean that the user fills/submits only `start_date` and leave the `venue` field untouched.

Comment: this has to be done in view , as you want to use two forms to perform validation.

Comment: @Neeraj That's indeed what I'm trying to do. As you can see from my question, I say that `type = cleaned_data.get('type')` in the view doesn't do that trick. I need to get the `type` from the other form. How?

Comment: the code has to written in event_edit_view() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dateEvent model modify the venue field, `venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)`

in event_edit_view() function, add the following lines of code

```
if form_date_event.is_valid() and form_event.is_valid()
    flag=False
    evt_type = form_event.cleaned_data.get('type')
    for form in form_date_event:
        if form.cleaned_data.get('venue') is None and evt_type !="recording release":
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        messages.error(request,'Venue can be blank only for recording release events')
        return render(request,myhtml.html,{'formset':form_date_event,'form':form_event})
    else:
        form_event.save()
        form_date_event.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it's not working as expected. I have a recording release which I want to save, with all fields filled except venue, and Django keeps redirecting me to the 'event edit' page each time I hit the save button with no errors displayed.

Comment: PS: I do have form_event.errors and form_date_event.errors in my template.

Comment: Have you modified the "venue" field in dateEvent?, All other event types are getting saved? Also are you able to save "recording release" with "venue"?

Comment: I forgot to edit the model, my bad. OK, so, I can save a performance with or without venue (which is not what I want: I want a compulsory venue for performance), while I am able to save a recording without venue now (that said, I want this to be only the case for recording).

Comment: can you print form.cleaned_data.get('venue') and form_event.cleaned_data.get('type') in your view when the you are leaving it blank and tell me what is getting printed. that value should be checked in "if" condition.

Comment: Apologies, I'm at a loss here, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: How can I pass it to the context? If I pass it to the context when I render the form I (rightly) get a `local variable 'evt_type' referenced before assignment`

Comment: above "if" statement write print(form.cleaned_data.get('venue'))

Comment: Your code makes sense reading it. Nevertheless, I am now not able to save a performance, whatever I input in the venue. I can save a recording, with or without venue, though. There's nothing printed in the page. Do I need to add anything to the template?

Comment: I put the whole `view` code in my question.

Comment: can you add one more condition in "if" if form.cleaned_data.get('venue') is None and evt_type !="recording release" and form.has_changed():

Comment: OK, I think I'm able to isolate the issue. If an event is already created as recording and I change its type to performance later, then I get that misbehaviour. If the performance is created and I leave the venue out I get the error message.

Comment: Since I think this is not something people will do, we can live with that.

Comment: ok, sounds good , so if your problem is solved can you accept the answer.